# Focus not setting on correct field after DoCmd.OpenForm

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am opening a form as follows.

```
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmPatient", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
```

Usually the default tab and field where the focus arrives is fine. But on some occasions I'd like to set it to a different field. I attempt to do so as follows in the next line of code:

```
    Forms("frmPatient")("cmdLabReport").SetFocus
```

For some reason this is not entirely working. The correct tab of the form is displayed but the wrong field is receiving the focus. I suspect it is because of intervening code that may still be executing in the background.

Comment: Order of form events: Open > Load > Resize > Activate > Current. I am not aware of TabMain event - what exactly is this?

Comment: You are correct, this isn't part of the standard flow of events. TabMain was the name I settled on for a TabControl on my Form. The actual method that seems to be part of the sequence of events is frmPatient.TabMain_Change. Perhaps it is called when I attempt to set the focus? I'm adding another bit of information to the original question concerning the effect of an intervening MsgBox invocation.

Comment: Access is not a multi-thread app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want code to fire after a `.SetFocus` due to events being triggered, follow-up with one or multiple `DoEvents`.

Access is fully synchronous, which means:

1. Your code runs
2. Any code that listened to events triggered by your code runs

If your code triggers an event, it gets processed either when your code finishes, or when you manually run `DoEvents`, which allows Access to process events.

Note that anything related to `SendKeys` is trouble. If you want to set focus to a particular control on a particular tab, do that, don't set focus to the tab and then use `SendKeys` to set the focus to the control.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm going to chuckle a bit while I observe these two statements in juxtaposition: Access is fully synchronous; `SendKeys` is trouble. Does that imply that `SendKeys` is asynchronous, or a crazy uncle living in the attic? For me to properly fix my code I'm going to have to figure out how to eliminate the need for `SendKeys` without which I'm unable figure out how to open tabs that have scrollable content and have them start out at the top position. For the proper StackOverflow content, that should be its own question, not handled here, I am assuming.

Comment: `SendKeys` mainly is trouble because it creates nightmares for someone that wants to do something you didn't account for. Say a few years later, someone chooses to automate your form and creates a script that opens up Access, opens your form, does stuff on it, presumably stuff happens, then closes it again, without Access being visible. That's suddenly impossible since Access can't properly use `SendKeys` when invisible. Someone adds a control to your application that changes the tab order, `SendKeys` suddenly starts navigating to different controls, etc.

Comment: You have no arguments from me there, having experienced the nightmares personally.

Comment: Oh, and for navigating to different pages without scrolling, do check an existing question doesn't answer your question already, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36504693/7296893) (try to navigate by setting the value of the tab control instead of using `SetFocus`)

Comment: I do my best to check for answers before I post, and yes, I almost always set the value of the tab control for navigation. The presence and spacing of content of material on the tabs by default is causing some of the tabs to scroll instead of opening scrolled to the top. For this new pathway in, I'll try having a sub on the form being opened do the tab selection prior to the setfocus. Perhaps if the tab is already set, the setfocus won't trigger the tab_change. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tab control "TabMain" on this form, and the control I'm setting the focus to is on a different tab that which the form normally opens. The tab control's Change event is triggered by the *SetFocus* command.

The last command in the *TabMain_Change* is a `SendKeys` command that sends a Tab. The reason for using this would involve a lot of explanation. Suffice it to say, it is this command that is changing my focus. The control on the form that gets the focus after my *SetFocus* command next on the tab index.

Curiously, if I open a `MsgBox` directly after the *SetFocus* command, the `SendKeys` that executes is applied to the `MsgBox` rather than the controls on *frmPatient*. So it seems there is some out-of-order something happening, as the `SendKeys` is executing after the `MsgBox` despite being called prior to it.

The code order:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmPatient", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
Forms("frmPatient")("cmdLabReport").SetFocus
MsgBox "Some messsage here", vbYesNo
```

*TabMain_Change* is called by the `.SetFocus`, and executes a `SendKeys`.
The above `MsgBox` opens with the focus set to "No" (in other words, one tab had been executed as this type of box usually opens with "Yes" as the default).

So, an ugly fix, I'll set the focus to the item with the tab index preceding the desired control. Ugly.